# Formatting the values of a multiselect using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap-3

I got the following multiselect defined in HTML:

```
<div class="col-sm-10">
    <select multiple class="form-control" id="los" name="los[]">
       {leden}
    </select>
</div>
```

Where {leden} will be populated on page load. Now I want to create a bootstrap modal that lists all the selected options in the multiple select. So far I've got:

```
("#los option:selected").text()
```

Which gives me all the textentries of the multiselect. However, I am unable to format that list. **Is there any way to create a string that contains "selected option 1, selected option 2, ..., selected option x"** so that I can use it in:

```
    btn.addEventListener("click", function(e){
            showBSModal({
                title: "Controleer gegevens",
                body: "De mail zal naar de volgende groep gestuurd worden:<br>" +
                $('#aan option:selected').text() + "<br><br>" +
                "De mail wordt ook naar de volgende personen gestuurd:<br>" +
                $('#email').val() + *The string of all selected items*
            )}
   };
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to loop and concat the selected options with comma to a string.

```
$( "#los" ).change(function() {
    var str = "";
    // loop all your selected options
    $( "#los option:selected" ).each(function() {
      // concat to a string with comma
      str += $( this ).text() + ", ";
    });
    // trim comma and white space at the end of string
    str = str.slice(0, -2);
  });
```

variable str will have the formatted selected options.

Comment: For anyone having the same problem: this answer solved it. My only addition was that I declared the variable str outside of the function scope because otherwise the other function could not access it :) Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

If you're looking to customize to that, try:

```
 var mySelectedOptions = '';
 ("#los option:selected").each(function(){
    mySelectedOptions += $(this).text()+", ";
 }
```

And then simply use `mySelectedOptions` for your formatted string.

Answer (score 0):

Short change event to show how to grab the selected elements, map an array of their values, and then join them into a string with ',' between them.

```js
$('#los').on('change', function(){
  console.log($('option:selected', this).map(function(){
    return this.innerHTML;
  }).get().join(','));
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select multiple class="form-control" id="los" name="los[]">
       <option>One</option>
       <option>Two</option>
       <option>Three</option>
       <option>Four</option>
    </select>
```